# Unknown null-distribution, known alternative distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, goodness-of-fit

I'm rather new to statistics, so please bear with me.

I would like to be able to say "to within 95% confidence, this data is exponentially-distributed." In this case, I know how the data *should* be distributed and I want to be able to say it *is* to some confidence.

In other words:

(Usually)

- $H_0$ = The data are exponentially-distributed.
- $H_a$ = The data are not exponentially-distributed.
- Choose a test statistic $T_\alpha$ such that Pr(T > $T_\alpha$) = $\alpha$ (under $H_0$).
- If T > $T_\alpha$, one can reject H_0 with confidence 1-$\alpha$.

(What I'd like)

- $H_0$ = The data are not exponentially-distributed.
- $H_a$ = The data are exponentially-distributed.
- ???
- Reject H_0 with confidence 1-$\alpha$.

I've also considered doing linear regression on the empirical CDF for the data, but I'm not sure how I would interpret the results of that in terms of confidence.

I apologize if this has been answered before, but I've searched considerably and haven't found anything helpful. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You seem to be asking a standard question about hypothesis tests, Sam: your "usually" appears to be exactly what you are aiming for. Alternatively, you might be seeking a Bayesian credible interval for the distribution parameters.

Comment: I've made a small edit which I hope will clarify. I'd like to be able to reject the hypothesis that "these data are *not* exponentially-distributed."

Perhaps this isn't really a well-formed null hypothesis, so hypothesis-testing isn't the right way to go about this task.

Comment: It is not a well-formed null. There are ways to deal with that.  Keywords to look for include [equivalence testing](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22equivalence%20testing%22), noninferiority testing, and [TOST](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3019319/).

Comment: @whuber i always thought this was impossible. seems like a dream come true for selecting a likelihood

Comment: Ah, equivalence testing seems to be exactly what I need. Thank you!

I'm curious, though. All I can find on it seems to be about establishing the equivalence of the means of two random variables with known distributions. How might I go about showing equivalence between two distributions?

Comment: @whuber ?

(Sorry. I didn't include your name in my earlier previous comment so I don't know if you saw)

Comment: I think you would need to adapt the idea of TOST. The most straightforward way would be to embed the exponential family in a larger family (of, say, two, three, or four parameters) that captures the likely deviations from exponentiality you might expect and then test those parameters for largish deviations from the values that would correspond to an exponential distribution. As you can see, answering this kind of question can get pretty involved: it's much easier to establish evidence that a hypothesis is *not* the case than it is to build strong evidence that it *is* the case.

Comment: @whuber I think your by now fairly extensive comments constitute an answer; by my reading, the OP seems to think so as well. I understand why you might prefer not to post one, but when you've pretty fully answered a question, you should probably actually post it as one (since we should generally avoid giving what are essentially complete answers in comments, and any impact of you answering the question has already occurred).

Answer (score 1):

If you can simulate data from your *alternate distribution*, could you then test whether the simulated distribution is the same as your *observed distribution* using the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) at the $\alpha=0.05$ level (not the same thing as a confidence interval, but still inference)?

Comment: I had considered the KS test. The problem is that I'm trying to reject the unknown distribution. The KS test allows me to say that I can reject a known distribution at the $\alpha$ level for data of an unknown distribution. At least, as I understand it.

Comment: I think this (conventional) abuse of language may be confusing you, Alexis: "*the* alternate distribution" refers to a family of possibilities governing the test statistic rather than a specific one. Without stipulating which one, you cannot perform a simulation. That is the crux of the distinction between null and alternative hypotheses.

Comment: Gotchya... I *was* assuming that @SamPatch had a specific alternate distribution in mind.